# Getting error TS2688 for something that doesn't actually exist

Tags: typescript

Right, so the issue here is with: `error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'inline-style-prefixer'.`

I have tried using `--traceResolution` to get more details, but all I get is: `/Users/<That's me!>/repo/work/<My project>/tsconfig.json
error TS` as the location of the error.

The `package.json` also has the dependency listed underneath devDependencies:

`devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/cli": "^3.2.3",
    "@storybook/react": "^3.2.3",
    "@types/axios": "^0.9.36",
    "@types/inline-style-prefixer": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/mathjs": "0.0.31",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.68",
    "@types/react": "^16.0.36",
    "@types/react-color": "^2.13.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^0.14.22",
    "@types/react-router": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
  ...`

No matter what I do, I keep getting that error. I have the `node_modules` folder excluded from the compilation.

How can I be getting an error for something I am not using?
I tried uninstalling it, as it was a dependency of another module all together. That changed nothing.

Edit: TypeScript version is `2.7.2`